# How to output a "." right after an object in Razor

Tags: razor

I have an object called item, item has a property itemId.  I am trying to build up a url that has the itemId followed by .html... so it would look like "myNiftyItem-123456.html"

```
@item.itemTitle-@item.itemId.html
```

Doesn't work as it thinks ".html" is a property or method of itemId.  How do I get that to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make an [explicit code nugget](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx):  `@item.itemTitle-@(item.itemId).html`

Comment: So what do you do if you wanted the output to be surrounded by "("s...like say I had a property itemCount... this doesn't work: (@item.itemCount)

Comment: (@item.itemCount) should work, can you update the question (or post a new one) with the error you're getting?